# Change component state - REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a project with the Pokemon API and i'm facing a problem.
I want to change the value parameter in the async function getPokemonTypes(), but the value I receive in handleSelect() is not working.
On the console.log(value), the value changes every time I select a different option.
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

async function getPokemonTypes(value) {

    const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${value}`)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    return data
}

async function getPokemonInfo(pokemonId) {

    const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`)
    const data = await response.json()
    return data
}


export const PokemonTypesCard = () => {

    const [pokemonTypesCard, setPokemonTypesCard] = useState({})
    const [pokemonIdNumber, setPokemonIdNumber] = useState([])
    const [value, setValue] = useState('normal')

    const handleSelect = (value) => {
        setValue(value)
      }
      console.log(value)
    useEffect(() => {

        async function fetchData() {

            const pokemonTypesCard = await getPokemonTypes(value)
            const pokemonIdText = pokemonTypesCard.pokemon.map((item) => {
                return item.pokemon.name
            })
            const data = pokemonIdText.map(async (pokemonId) => {
                return (
                    await getPokemonInfo(pokemonId)
                )
            })
            const pokemonIdNumber = await Promise.all(data)
            setPokemonIdNumber(pokemonIdNumber)
            setPokemonTypesCard(pokemonTypesCard)
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <section>

            <div>
                <label htmlFor='pokemon-types'>Choose a pokemon type</label>
                <form>
                    <select onChange={(event) => handleSelect(event.target.value)}
        value={value}>
                        <option value='normal'>Normal</option>
                        <option value='fighting'>Fighting</option>
                        <option value='flying'>Flying</option>
                        <option value='poison'>Poison</option>
                        <option value='ground'>Ground</option>
                        <option value='rock'>Rock</option>
                        <option value='bug'>Bug</option>
                        <option value='ghost'>Ghost</option>
                        <option value='steel'>Steel</option>
                        <option value='fire'>Fire</option>
                        <option value='water'>Water</option>
                        <option value='grass'>Grass</option>
                        <option value='electric'>Electric</option>
                        <option value='psychic'>Psychic</option>
                        <option value='ice'>Ice</option>
                        <option value='dragon'>Dragon</option>
                        <option value='dark'>Dark</option>
                        <option value='fairy'>Fairy</option>
                        <option value='shadow'>Shadow</option>
                    </select>
                </form>

            </div>

            {<div>
                <ul>
                    {!pokemonIdNumber ? '' : pokemonIdNumber.map((item, index) =>
                        <li key={index}>
                            <Link to={`/pokemon/${item.id}`}>
                                <img
                                    src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${item.id}.png`}
                                    alt={item.name}
                                />
                            </Link>
                            <p>{item.name}</p>
                        </li>
                    )}
                </ul>
            </div>}

        </section>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `type` to the dependnecies array of [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const pokemonTypesCard = await getPokemonTypes(value);
        const pokemonIdText = pokemonTypesCard.pokemon.map((item); => {
            return item.pokemon.name;
        });
        const data = pokemonIdText.map(async (pokemonId) => {
            return (
                await getPokemonInfo(pokemonId)
            );
        });
        const pokemonIdNumber = await Promise.all(data);
        setPokemonIdNumber(pokemonIdNumber);
        setPokemonTypesCard(pokemonTypesCard);
    }

    fetchData();
}, [value]); // <= HERE
```

Keep in mind this code has some issues, as you might end up seeing data for a type that doesn't match the one in the URL if something like this happens:

- You select `fire` and `getPokemonTypes('fire')` is called.
- You select to `ice` and `getPokemonTypes('ice')` is called.
- `getPokemonTypes('ice')` finishes loading and the rest of the `fetchData` function executes.
- `getPokemonTypes('fire')` finishes loading and the rest of the `fetchData` function executes.
- The selected option is now `ice` but see data from `fire`.

The proper way to do it would be like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let shouldUpdate = true;

    async function fetchData() {
        const pokemonTypesCard = await getPokemonTypes(value);

        if (!shouldUpdate) return;

        const pokemonIdText = pokemonTypesCard.pokemon.map((item) => {
            return item.pokemon.name;
        });

        const data = pokemonIdText.map((pokemonId) => {
            return getPokemonInfo(pokemonId);
        });

        const pokemonIdNumber = await Promise.all(data);

        if (!shouldUpdate) return;

        setPokemonIdNumber(pokemonIdNumber);
        setPokemonTypesCard(pokemonTypesCard);
    }

    fetchData();

    // This cleanup function will be called if the `useEffect`'s
    // dependencies change, so if you run it twice in a row for
    // different types, when the result of the first one arrives,
    // it will be discarded:
    return () => {
        shouldUpdate = false;
    };
}, [value]);
```

Also, you have an error here:

```
const data = pokemonIdText.map(async (pokemonId) => {
    return (
        await getPokemonInfo(pokemonId)
    );
});

const pokemonIdNumber = await Promise.all(data);
```

You want to store all those promises in the `data` array and await them all together with `Promise.all` below, but you are instead awaiting them one by one. It should be like this:

```
const data = pokemonIdText.map((pokemonId) => {
    return getPokemonInfo(pokemonId);
});

const pokemonIdNumber = await Promise.all(data);
```